# Invalid Character Base64 Firebase.Storage()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, base64, firebase-storage

I have been trying to post an image to Firebase.Storage() for over a week now with no success. First using a blob/file which ended up not working due to Node.JS not having a blob type. Now with posting as base64. I have tried every fix I could find on here with no success. The error I am getting is:

> Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64: Invalid character found

---

### client side

```
handleImage = ( event ) => {
    const target = event.target
    const files = target.files

    if (files.length > 0) {
        const fileToLoad = files[0];

        const fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = event => {
            const srcData = event.target.result; // data: base64
            console.log(srcData)
            let encodedImage = srcData.split(/,(.+)/)[1];

            const options = {
                file: encodedImage,
                fileName: fileToLoad.name
            }

            axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/dashboard/post-image`, options)
        }
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad)
    } 
}
```

---

### server side

```
router.post('/post-image', (req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.body.file)

const fileName = req.body.fileName
const message = req.body.file
const storageRef = firebase.app().storage().ref()

storageRef.child(`${fileName}`).putString(message, 'base64')
    .then(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot, 'uploaded image')
    })
```

})

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try doing typeof message to see if it really is base64?

Comment: This site has a minimal example of a string you can hard-code to test with: http://png-pixel.com/. I'm actually not sure if you need the `data:image/png;base64,` prefix, so be sure to test both.